# Spontaneous emergence of replicators in Artificial Life

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

One of the corner stones of The Selfish Gene (Dawkins) is the spontaneous emergence of replicators, i.e. molecules capable of replicating themselves.

Has this been modeled *in silico* in open-ended evolutionary / artificial life simulations?

Systems like Avida or Tierra explicitly specify *the* replication mechanisms; other genetic algorithm/genetic programming systems explicitly search *for* the replication mechanisms (e.g. to simplify the von Neumann universal constructor)

Links to simulations where replicators emerge from a primordial digital soup are welcome.

Comment: This question seems more suitable for [AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The software system Amoeba by Andrew Pargellis has studying the origins of life as an explicit goal; he saw interesting patterns developing first, that eventually turned into self-replicators.

More recently (well, 2011) Evan Dorn used Avida to study a range of questions to do with the origin of life, with a focus on astrobiology.  They wanted to examine how chemical distributions changed as abotic environments shifted to biotic so that astronomers would know what to look for.

For a good starting point, take a look at:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00239-011-9429-4